# Extract Text after Second Underscore in Excel from right side

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Need to extract text between first and second "_" from string in a cell.

Example - `88/12_PO/SP_SJ_#448491_WHITE_10A_60`

Required to extract "10A" from above string

```
=MID(B2, SEARCH("_",B2) + 1, SEARCH("_",B2,SEARCH("_",B2)+1) - SEARCH("_",B2) - 1)
```

Comment: What version of excel?

Comment: As a minor note, `_` is an underscore.  `,` is a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me chuck in some options for you to consider:

---

**VBA:**

Not my forte, but I'd use the `Split()` option here:

```
Function SPLITTEXT(s As String, del As String, Optional indx As Long = 1) As String

If indx < 0 Then
    s = StrReverse(s)
    SPLITTEXT = StrReverse(Split(s, del)(Abs(indx) - 1))
Else
    SPLITTEXT = Split(s, del)(Application.Max(indx, 1)- 1)
End If

End Function
```

Or, maybe:

```
Function SPLITTEXT(s As String, del As String, Optional indx As Long = 1) As String

Dim r As Variant: r = Split(s, del)

If indx < 0 Then
    SPLITTEXT = r(UBound(r) + indx - 1)
Else
    SPLITTEXT = r(Application.Max(indx, 1) - 1)
    
End If

End Function
```

Call like `=SPLITTEXT(A1,"_",-2)` where I tried to mimic the `TEXTBEFORE()` 3rd parameter to let you pick an index from left *or* right.

---

**Excel ms365**:

```
=@TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"_"),,-2)
```

---

**Excel 2013 and up for Windows**:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]/preceding::*[1]")
```

Or:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() = last()-1]")
```

Comment: JvdV, the king of Excel formulas. Kudos.

Comment: That's too much credit @FunThomas.

Comment: King of FilterXML definitely.

Comment: Absolutely Correct King of Formulas, Aka `Regex` as well. As **Enigmativity** would say steely-eyed missile man!!!

Comment: The formula provided by @TigerAvatar deserves more kudos and could possibly be a better fit for OP's version of Excel (which we don't know at this point).

Comment: True, very usable for non-Windows users with older Excel that don't have access to vba

Answer (score 3):

The `*2` is the count from right side, so it will return the 2nd from right side.  Changing it to `*3` would return the 3rd from right side (WHITE in your example):

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"_",REPT(" ",LEN(B2))),LEN(B2)*2),LEN(B2)))
```

Answer (score 3):

As you tagged VBA: This could be a UDF to use.
Default separator is "_", but you can specify any other separator character
Default piece is the 2nd last (index = -2), but you can ask for any other position

```
Function extract(word As String, Optional separator As String = "_", Optional ByVal index As Long = -2)
    ' index = 1 gives first word, 2 gives 2nd word...
    ' index -1 gives last word, -2 gives 2nd last word...
    Dim tokens() As String
    tokens = Split(word, separator)
    If index < 0 Then index = UBound(tokens) + index + 1 Else index = index - 1
    If index >= 0 And index <= UBound(tokens) Then extract = tokens(index)
End Function
```

Just use a formula like `=Extract(B2)` in Excel

Answer (score 1):

You can do it that way, if you need it in many steps :

```
Dim sMyString As String
Dim Pos1 As Long
Dim Pos2 As Long
Dim Result As String

sMyString = "88/12_PO/SP_SJ_#448491_WHITE_10A_60"

Pos1 = InStrRev(sMyString, "_")
Pos2 = InStrRev(sMyString, "_", Pos1 - 1)
Result = Mid(sMyString, Pos2 + 1, Pos1 - 1 - Pos2) 'this will return 10A
```

You can also put this in a function

```
Public Function ExtractString(sMyString As String) As String

Dim Pos1 As Long
Dim Pos2 As Long
Dim Result As String

Pos1 = InStrRev(sMyString, "_")
Pos2 = InStrRev(sMyString, "_", Pos1 - 1)
ExtractString = Mid(sMyString, Pos2 + 1, Pos1 - 1 - Pos2)

End Function
```